# Compute the minimal radius $r$ such that $B_r(a) \cap B_r(b) \cap B_r(c) \ne\varnothing$

Tags: geometry

Let $a, b, c \in \mathbf{R}^2$. I am interested in finding the minimal radius $r$ such that $r$ such that $B_r(a) \cap B_r(b) \cap B_r(c) \ne\varnothing$, where $B_r(p)$ denotes the closed ball of radius $r$ about $p$. I know how to check if there is such a triple intersection for a given $r$, but I did not manage to turn this into a way to compute $r$.

Comment: One can consider function $f(t)$, $t\in \mathbb{R}^2$, such that $f(t)$ is maximum of distances from $t$ to $a$, $b$, $c$. Then $r$ is minimum of $f(t)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$M:=\{R\in\mathbb{R} |\,B_R(a)\cap B_R(b)\cap B_R(c) \neq \emptyset \}$$
$$r:= \min M$$
and
$$m:=\frac{1}{2}\max\{\text{dist}(a,b),\text{dist}(a,c),\text{dist}(b,c)\}$$
Then first we notice, that trivially
$$r\geq m.$$ Thus if $m\in M$, then $r=m.$

We have to distinguish two cases. The points $a,b,c$ form a triangle.

**Case 1:** The triangle is obtuse. Then you can show using the properties of obtuse triangles (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_and_obtuse_triangles#Inequalities)) that indeed $m\in M$ and thus $r=m$.

**Case 2:** The triangle is acute. Here $m\notin M$. However in this case the [circumcenter](https://testbook.com/learn/maths-circumcenter-of-a-triangle/) $O$ of the triangle lies inside of it, it has the same distance to $a,b,c$ respectively. Your solution is then $r=\text{dist}(a,O)$. You can see that this must be the minimal solution, because $B_r(a)\cap B_r(b)\cap B_r(c) = \{O\}$ which can not be optimized.

**Case 3:** The triange is right-angled. In this case the above solutions coincide $r = m = dist(a,O)$.

Comment: [+1] good answer.